# Should I use locally stored images or network loaded images in react-native?

Tags: react-native

As there are 2 ways to render an image in react-native. 
One is locally stored images which could be accessed via require and Second is network fetched image which could be user via passing uri.

I wanted to know which way should be preferred for small images like icons/symbols etc?
What are the pros and cons for both in terms of performance/rendering since there is no fallback option in react-native for Android?

Answer (score 3):

This pretty much depends on developer preference and requirement of the projects.

Bundling static assets in app can reduce the loading time since there will be no network requests but remote images can help reduce the size of the app.

Having long cache times with the network images can reduce the requests. Also using network images make you able to update them without updating the app itself. Using some sort of a sprite with static images can help size and control of the assets.

In the end it really depends on your preference.